# How to include Guzzle in a wordpress theme/plugin

Tags: wordpress, guzzle

How can i include Guzzle into a wordpress theme or plugin. Since the theme/plugins will be distributed to non tech users i cannot ask them to do that via Composer.

I have uploaded the guzzle pack in a theme folder in libs/resources/ and in functions.php and I have defined this autoloader for guzzle classes only

```
spl_autoload_register( 'guzzle_autoloader' );
function guzzle_autoloader( $class_name ) {
  if ( false !== strpos( $class_name, 'GuzzleHttp' ) ) {
  $classes_dir = realpath( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) ) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'libs' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'resources'. DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .'guzzle-master'. DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .'src'. DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR ;

  $replace="GuzzleHttp\\";
  $class_file = str_replace($replace,'', $class_name);

  print 'request '.$classes_dir . $class_file.'</br>';

  require_once $classes_dir . $class_file.'.php';

  }
 }
```

However i'm still getting this error "call to undefined function GuzzleHttp\choose_handler() "

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 11):

What about composer autoload?

1. Simply Require Guzzle packagist repo with composer

   ```
    composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle
   ```
2. Install

   ```
    composer install
   ```
3. Simply autoload Guzzle Classes in your Wordpress plugin

   ```
    require 'vendor/autoload.php';
    //use GuzzleHttp\Client;
   ```

Comment: If you plan to distribute the plugin with the Guzzle library, it should be prefixed/scoped to avoid namespace conflicts with other libraries or plugins. I've created this plugin to show how it could be done. https://github.com/PHP-Prefixer/using-guzzle-in-a-word-press-plug-in-with-php-prefixer